# Trying to obtain closest value to known key from user input | numpy.core_exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Im trying to write a text-based sports game and part of that game is deciding who wins tip off based on comparing user input to a known value, and deciding the winner based on which user is closest.

I used NumPy to convert a list containing the values, into an array, then find the absolute difference of each value with K and obtaining the minimum from it

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/***/PycharmProjects/MyFirsyPycharm/Sports_Game/basketballgame.py", line 33, in <module>
    tipoff(player_one_tip, player_two_tip)
  File "/Users/***/PycharmProjects/MyFirsyPycharm/Sports_Game/basketballgame.py", line 11, in tipoff
    tipoff_winner = closest(tipoff_value, 50)
  File "/Users/***/PycharmProjects/MyFirsyPycharm/Sports_Game/basketballgame.py", line 6, in closest
    idx = (np.abs(lst - K)).argmin()
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U3'), dtype('<U3')) -> dtype('<U3')
```

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def closest(lst, K):
    lst = np.asarray(lst)
    idx = (np.abs(lst - K)).argmin()
    return lst[idx]

def tipoff(p_one, p_two):
    tipoff_value = [p_one, p_two]
    tipoff_winner = closest(tipoff_value, 50)
    print(tipoff_winner)
    if (tipoff_winner == p_one):
        print("Player one has selected the correct value and has won the tip off")
    elif (tipoff_winner == p_two):
        print("PLayer two has selected the correct choice and won the tip_off")


print("Welcome to NBA Basketball 1 on 1!")

player_one = input("Player one, what is your name?")
print(player_one)

player_two = input("Player two, what is your name?")
print(player_two)

print(f"Welcome today's game is \n {player_one} \nvs \n  {player_two}")

player_one_tip = input("Player one, select a number between 1 and 100")

player_two_tip = input("Player two, select a number between 1 and 100")

tipoff(player_one_tip, player_two_tip)
```

Not asking for answers but can someone point direct me to what im missing? Or please let me know if im going about this the entirely wrong way

Comment: The error says you're trying to subtract strings, not numbers. You have a string-valued array rather than a numeric array.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I am a colossal moron. I changed the inputs to int(input()) and got it to work. Leaving this up for anyone that is as boneheaded as me. Thank you!

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself, some mistakes are more obvious in hindsight :) At least you're unlikely to make this mistake ever again. (Most people making the same mistake will likely not find your question, however.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `input` takes the number as string.

You should change to:

```
player_one_tip = int(input("Player one, select a number between 1 and 100"))

player_two_tip = int(input("Player two, select a number between 1 and 100"))
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I can't believe I made such a boneheaded mistake. Code is working as intended now after the changes. Thank you

Comment: If @Rahul Vishwakarma have solved your problem, you should consider accepting his answer as a solution.